# how to search tags not matching pattern

Tags: vim

In my xml file, i have many location tags. eg:

```
 <location>file:///home/faizal/Music/THE%20DOORS/Studio%20albums/2007%20Infected%20Mushroom%20Presents%20-%20The%20Doors%20Remixed%20(2%20CD)%20@320/CD2/07%20Break%20on%20Through%20(Infected%20Mushroom%20Guitar%20Rmx).mp3</location>
```

I would like to find all location tags that do not start with `file:///home/faizal/Music/`. How would i go about writing a vim command to do this?

The below command does not exclude lines with the `file:///home/faizal/Music/` pattern. what am i doing wrong?

```
/^\(.*\<location\c\>\)\&\(.*file\:\/\/\/home\/home\/faizal\/Music\)\@!
```

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883985/vim-regex-how-to-search-for-a-and-b-not-c

Comment: @muru that's a good post, but it doesn't seem to work for me. A simple `^\(.*Location\)\@!` gives me the error : `E492: Not an editor command: ^\(.*Location\)\@!`

Comment: Those are regular expressions, not commands. Either use them in a search: `/^\(.*location\)\@!` or in a command: `:g/^\(.*location\)\@!`

Comment: @muru ahh that makes sense

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: @muru the command works, but not to my exact requirement. I have edited the question with the command i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
/\v(.*\<location\>)&(.*file:\/\/\/home\/faizal\/Music)@!
```

- `\v` means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
  '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
- `@!` is a negative assertion
- `.` matches any character
- `*` matches any number of the previous atom
- `&` is the boolean AND
- `()` is grouping into an atom
- `/` is the find command
- `\` is the escape character

Reference : http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883985/vim-regex-how-to-search-for-a-and-b-not-c

Thanks @muru